# The difference between a button and a label

Tags: .net, vb.net

As far as a click event procedure goes will a button and a label do the same thing. I notice that you can hide a button under a label but cant hide a label under a button. Why? Can you start off with a labels text saying one thing but at a certain point in the programs execution make say something different?

Comment: "Can you start off with a labels text saying one thing but at a certain point in the programs execution make say something different" - [Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d.aspx)

Comment: You can hide anything behind anything else, you just have to be creative on how to do that. Are you doing Windows forms, or ASP.NET? Also the answer to your last question is yes, just use the [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d.aspx) property of the label.

Comment: Any `OnClick` that fires as a result of a mouse click on a forms control will execute whatever code is in the click event. As for the designer, you should be able to 'send-to-back' or 'bring-to-front' on any control, and the order of display will depend on that. And in your code, `label1.Text = "Something"` will change the text of the label (or any number of other controls with the `Text` property) on the form to whatever you set it to.

Comment: I'd say the easiest answer is the default design of the control.  You could do a lot of work and make a label look a lot like a button, or you could just use a button.

Answer (score 4):

They both raise the Click event when you click them with the mouse, there's no difference in there.

Of course a Button is a lot more adept at the task.  It *looks* like something that's clickable, the user will have no trouble discovering that.  He'll never think of clicking a Label, that requires a manual.  And a Button can receive the focus and can be clicked without using the mouse.  Press the Tab key to set the focus, press the Spacebar to click it.  Also the reason that the Click event doesn't pass the mouse position like the MouseClick event does.  Power-users favor this, operating UI with the keyboard can be a lot faster than using a mouse.  Also the kind of user that makes the recommendation to purchase a license to your program so you don't really want to displease them with a non-standard or difficult to use UI.

Hiding a Label under a button is no problem, you just got the get the Z-order right.  Right-click the button in the designer and choose Bring to Front.  This of course requires a good reason, the label won't be visible to the user so has very little value.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost I must say that I do not quite understand what you want...

However,choose whether control should be over or under or inside a control read:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/30/document-outline-windows-form-projects-vstiptool0118.aspx

About everything can be changed as you wish, but with Visual Studio and. NET, Microsoft has made ​​a base that enables faster developing we can create what we want.
Therefore, I recommend using the control that meant for it, if possible! Each control different events and propertys.

If u look at :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick.aspx

Textbox Control inherit from TextBoxBase so:

> Public MustInherit Class TextBoxBase
>             Inherits **System.Windows.Forms.Control**
>        Member of System.Windows.Forms Summary: Implements the basic functionality required by text controls.

Label Control:

> Public Class Label
>             Inherits **System.Windows.Forms.Control**
>        Member of System.Windows.Forms Summary: Represents a standard Windows label.

So you see that onClick is under System.Windows.Forms.Control then all classes that inherit from System.Windows.Forms.Control will have onclik Event.